# How to draw a directional arrow head

Tags: ios, swift3, uibezierpath

I have lines in many directions and angles, I draw them using `UIBezierpath`.

I need to draw an arrow on one of the ends of the line; dynamically depending on given point.

**Edit:** [image: hand drawn but should give you a better understandin]

**Edit 2:** with Jake answer here is my code

```
let y2 = line.point2Y

let path = UIBezierPath()

  path.move(to: CGPoint(x: x1, y: y1))
  path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: x2, y: y2))
path.addArrow(start: CGPoint(x: x1, y: y1), end: CGPoint(x: x2, y: y2), pointerLineLength: ...
path.close()

let shape = CAShapeLayer()
let shapeBorder = CAShapeLayer()
shapeBorder.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
shapeBorder.lineJoin = kCALineJoinRound
shapeBorder.lineCap = kCALineCapRound
shapeBorder.lineWidth = 10
shapeBorder.addSublayer(shape)

shape.path = path.cgPath
shapeBorder.path = shape.path
shape.lineJoin = kCALineJoinRound
shape.lineCap = kCALineCapRound
shape.lineWidth = shapeBorder.lineWidth-5.0
shape.strokeColor = color
```

But there is a shadow [image]

Comment: I will check it, thanks

Comment: More info needed...arrow size, arrow direction, arrow position, etc

Comment: Direction is dynamic, it could point to any angle of 360 degrees.

Comment: Size does not matters, the tip of the arrow will be always one of the 2 points of any line

Comment: [whathaveyoutried.com](https://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Please put your code in text in the question, not images. Your issue is the `fillColor` of your layer. Set it to `UIColor.clear.cgColor`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This works for me:

```
extension UIBezierPath {
    func addArrow(start: CGPoint, end: CGPoint, pointerLineLength: CGFloat, arrowAngle: CGFloat) {
        self.move(to: start)
        self.addLine(to: end)

        let startEndAngle = atan((end.y - start.y) / (end.x - start.x)) + ((end.x - start.x) < 0 ? CGFloat(Double.pi) : 0)
        let arrowLine1 = CGPoint(x: end.x + pointerLineLength * cos(CGFloat(Double.pi) - startEndAngle + arrowAngle), y: end.y - pointerLineLength * sin(CGFloat(Double.pi) - startEndAngle + arrowAngle))
        let arrowLine2 = CGPoint(x: end.x + pointerLineLength * cos(CGFloat(Double.pi) - startEndAngle - arrowAngle), y: end.y - pointerLineLength * sin(CGFloat(Double.pi) - startEndAngle - arrowAngle))

        self.addLine(to: arrowLine1)
        self.move(to: end)
        self.addLine(to: arrowLine2)
    }
}

class MyViewController : UIViewController {
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        let arrow = UIBezierPath()
        arrow.addArrow(start: CGPoint(x: 200, y: 200), end: CGPoint(x: 50, y: 50), pointerLineLength: 30, arrowAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi / 4))

        let arrowLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        arrowLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        arrowLayer.lineWidth = 3
        arrowLayer.path = arrow.cgPath
        arrowLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        arrowLayer.lineJoin = kCALineJoinRound
        arrowLayer.lineCap = kCALineCapRound
        self.view.layer.addSublayer(arrowLayer)
    }
}
```

[image]

**EDIT**

Also, make sure you set your the `fillColor` of your `CAShapeLayer` to `UIColor.clear.cgColor`. Otherwise, your layer will fill in the area between the start point of the arrow and one of the lines at the end.

Comment: Well it worked fine, but still a small issue from what seems my code will edit the question

Comment: Thank you very much you are a life saver

Comment: How can I set the anchor point of this to the bottom left? I have this implemented and it's beginning reference seems to be the top left of the screen rather than the bottom left as all my other code. I am using constants of other objects to reference it on the screen and it "flips" the y direction. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59791882/swift-uibezierpath-adding-objects-to-incorrect-locations?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 1):

Great example, thanks for posting @Jake. Small update, with Xcode 12 it should be:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    let arrow = UIBezierPath()
    arrow.addArrow(start: CGPoint(x: 200, y: 200), end: CGPoint(x: 50, y: 50), pointerLineLength: 30, arrowAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi / 4))

    let arrowLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    arrowLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    arrowLayer.lineWidth = 3
    arrowLayer.path = arrow.cgPath
    arrowLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    arrowLayer.lineJoin = CAShapeLayerLineJoin.round
    arrowLayer.lineCap = CAShapeLayerLineCap.round
    self.view.layer.addSublayer(arrowLayer)
}
```